# Pattern not escaping characters

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I've got this pattern which I use with preg_match and I can't figure where I go wrong.

```
$pattern = "{(\[fn:)([0-9]*)(\])((?:\\\[|[^\[])*)}";
```

It has to match each **[fn:i]text_multiline** untill another one starts so when it meets **[** and i want to escapte the **[** by **\[** from the following example:

> [fn:1] This is the text for \[this needs to be escaped] footnote 1.
>
> Note that it could be multiple paragraphs.
>
> [fn:2] This is the text for footnote 2.

This is the matches that I get at the moment:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "[fn:1]"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "[fn:"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "]"
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: Your delimiters have to match. You can't use `{` and `}`

Comment: I really don't think that is the problem. I've used pattern with this delimiters before and it worked fine.

Comment: Hmm, I guess those are valid delimiters. I didn't know that would work. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique to use when you want to exclude and escaped [ is called "negative look behind".

For example,

```
(?<!\\)\[
```

This regex will match [ but ignore if its proceeded by a \

Let me know if you need any more help

**Edit #1**

This is the negative lookbehind applied to your specific scenario

```
\[fn:\d+](?:\\\[|[^[])*
```

and in php this becomes

```
if (preg_match('/\[fn:\d+\](?:\\\\\[|[^[])*/', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Some notes

- I use alternation and let it first match the escaped [ so it doesn't get excluded by what matches after the alternation (common trick that relies on the order in alternation)
- I started from scratch so if you need to capture some groups then add parenthesis where needed
- The construct (?:) is used to group but not to capture. This is (maybe) more efficient and as said I left out the capturing

The regex is tested against your example. Let me know if you can get it working now

Good luck, Buckley

Comment: I can't manage to integrate it in the original pattern. I've tried **"{(\[fn:)([0-9]*)(\])(((?<!\\)\[)*)}"** and **"{(\[fn:)([0-9]*)(\])((?<!\\)\[*)}"**

Comment: It should be four backslashes in the lookbehind. PHPs string tokenizer eats up one level of escaping.

Comment: @mario can you please help me out. I still can't figure this out

Comment: @alex I applied the negative lookbehind in the answer above. It's a very powerful technique worth mastering.

Comment: @alex Sure no problem. Shoot if you have any more questions

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace_all("#\\[(?!fn:\\d+\\])#", "\\[")` will do the trick, but it's better not to use regexps for that.